# Changes are not showing up (.Net 4.5 MVC application on IIS)

Tags: c#, .net, iis

We have .Net 4.5 MVC application deployed on IIS, on front end we are using durandal but I don't think the issue is related to durandal. The thing is there is critical bug in production app and I need to fix it, I made a copy of the application and deployed to IIS in default websites. The problem is when I make changes to html or js it's not showing up, its returning the old html/js. Since I cannot debug it I am using alerts. For example I set alert text to 'update 1' then make changes and then increment it to 'update 2' but I am still getting 'update 1' and none of the changes. I have tried the following

1) refeshing the web page

2) refreshing the web page with ctr+shift+r

3) try with another browser

4) try on different device

At this point I figured it might be IIS issue and I tried the following

1) changing web.config (i.e. when web.config changes even if you add space IIS should get latest version)

2) set clientCache to 0

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="0.00:00:00" />
</staticContent
```

3) refreshing the application from IIS

I deleted contents of home page html/js doing so should throw exception but the app is working as before. At this point I have no clue and would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Ensure you are looking at the right server.  If you have multiple environments (dev/staging/prod) ensure you are updating the expected environment.  Add a text file or image sample file that would be server directly - request this file to confirm you are on the right location.

Comment: I can see the chagens in couple of hours, so yeah I am changing the application files on the right server

Comment: @Abdurakhmon Are you only updating the `View` or uploading the entire publish folder?

Comment: only html and js files

Comment: If the changes take a couple of hours, do you have any type of cache enabled?  Also, adding alerts in prod is probably not a good idea as it will hamper user experience - use `console.log()` instead or ideally do problem analysis in dev. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: Its not actually production that clients use, I made copy of it and making changes there

Comment: @Abdurakhmon Not quite sure but I feel that there is some configuration problem with the server. If it is taking couple of hours to for the changes to reflect, you need to check the Event Viewer Logs in IIS to investigate what could potentially be going wrong.

Comment: Could you please tell me when you access the web application from client side or on  the server's browser? Does your web application has CDN or something else like this? I suggest you could try to create a new web sites with the new created html file to make sure it works well.

Comment: It was from minified files, I deleted them and my changes showed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below things:

1. Check package you created is the latest one
2. Check minified filed is updated
3. Reset IIS after deployment
4. Reset application pool

Comment: It was from minified files